# Connect Excel to Smartsheet via Power Query

Tags: smartsheet-api, powerquery

I have been trying to pull data from one of my Sheets in Smartsheet using Power Query without no luck. I generated an API token from Smartsheet that I used in the Power Query Wizard but still failed.

Answer (score 2):

1. In power query editor I basically hardcoded the authorization header + API token:

```
= Web.Contents(
    "https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheet/4693183612381060", 
    [
        Headers = [
            #"Authorization" = "Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN"
        ]
    ]
)
```

2. Then when prompted to enter credentials on the next screen, I chose Anonymous instead of Web API, as someone suggested in the comments here

http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/getting-data-into-power-query-with-the-twitter-search-api-how-to-hack-pq-to-use-oauth/

Comment: Yes, PQ documentation is not very clear, and the UI connection options are confusing.  Thanks for posting the connection instructions.